# Datetimepicker de Tempusdominus en label html

Tags: bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

tengo un label que tiene de id lblFecha, me gustaría poder hacer click sobre ese label y que se desplegará el datetimepicker  para poder selecionar la fecha  y que la fecha seleccionada se asignada a esa label.

Sobre un campo input type text me funciona bien, el problema es cuando es una label

```html
<table class=" table table-sm  text-center">
  <thead >
    <tr class="header">
   <th> <i class='fa fa-calendar' aria-hidden='true'></i> <label  id="lblFecha"class=" header"></label></th>
   <th> <i class='fa fa-user-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i> <label  id="lblNombre" class="header  "></label></th>
   <th> <i class='fa fa-truck fa-1x' aria-hidden='true'></i> <label  id="lblCamion" class=" header cursor   "></label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
```

```js
$('#lblFecha').datetimepicker({
 format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/es.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class=" table table-sm  text-center">
  <thead >
    <tr class="header">
   <th> <i class='fa fa-calendar' aria-hidden='true'></i> <label  id="lblFecha">Fecha</label></th>
  
    </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
```